# SharePoint External List, Memory Leakage

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, idisposable

would there be a memory leak if I would to return a external list to the caller using a method as shown below?

```
    public static SPList getList(string listName)
               {
                    SPList list = null;
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[WebName])
                        {
                            list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                            return list;
                        }
                     }
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? top of my head, the web is closed outside this method, and any operation on the List is not allowed. Suggest to return a DataTable

Comment: i second that, this will probably not work because of the disposing before using the list...

Answer (score 0):

may be you should pass the SPWeb object to your getList method and dispose it outside getList method.